# A question about Status Snapshot and re-rendering from react document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

A question from react document:

for below example here is my understanding:

- on change <input> element triggers rerender
- State "text" should be updated after rerendering
- for the time handleSend() was called (the timeout was set), "text" holds the initial value
- after 3 seconds the callback was executed, "text" should be updated if we have changed value in the input box, because the component's already rerendered.

The rerender must happen way faster before the callback, can't figure out why it still prints the initial value and useRef() must be used instead.

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Chat() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  function handleSend() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('Sending: ' + text);
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={text}
        onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={handleSend}>
        Send
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs
challenges #4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think above is just how Javascript works. Following would be my hypotheses of the phenomena.

When you create / define a function, it assigns a reference to it, Even though your execution of `alert` is delayed, you are initiating `handleSend`  with value of `text` intact.

When you define a function, its similar to `Object` (you can read it ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#description))). Hence when it gets invoked, its invoking that particular referenced function only.

Which has the older value of specific variable, as states are references as well, it won't read the updated value, due to having used older reference as value in the function definition.

Comment: then it would be weird for `alert('Sending: ' + textRef.current);` to use the latest value of `const textRef = useRef(text);` in Solution since `textRef.current` should remain the value in function definition as well.

Comment: Value is stored within a property of the reference, While textRef is staying same, but `.current` is updated. Its similar to how you directly update a property of Object from state, it will reflect new value in console, but won't show up in rendering.

Comment: oh, so when the timeout function executes, the reference `text` still points to the original state, despite the component had been re-rendered, and a new state `text` was already created on that moment, it still looks in the initial component (which has been unloaded and may get recycled after a while). Do I explain it right?

Comment: Yes, you did. Its a function at the end of everything. So, everything works just like a simple javascript would. Re-rendering of component, re-define things. That's how they are using `useMemo` and `useCallback` as well.